# Recent activity glitch

Tags: bug

[This question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30420/how-much-pressure-can-mountain-bike-tires-take) showed up on the front page as modified 7 hours ago (about 1900UT Saturday 8/22) by Daniel R Hicks.  When I clicked through I don't see any modification recently.  He commented on May 7 and I don't see any recent activity on the question at all.

Comment: Could be something occurred that you can't see. He might have deleted something. Or done something else, since with his rep he has access to moderator tools. It will take him or a moderator to explain properly though.

Comment: Also possible than an edit was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the timeline available to moderators, it looks like the activities that bumped up the question were two answers posted that were ultimately determined to be spam. These answers were deleted.